# What is the correct approach to create an Event in Apex for another User with their Timezone?

Tags: apex, datetime, event, timezone, calendar

I'm trying to create an event for another user which needs to appear on their Calendar (in that user's Timezone).

e.g. Current user's Timezone is Australia/Sydney, I need to create an event for a New Zealand user with timezone Pacific/Auckland.

When you simply create an event below it's getting saved in current user's Timezone.

```
DateTime eventStart = Datetime.newInstance(2019, 11, 14, 10, 0, 0);
DateTime eventEnd = Datetime.newInstance(2019, 11, 14, 10, 30, 0);

    insert new Event(OwnerId = userIdwithDifferentTimezone,StartDateTime = eventStart, EndDateTime = eventEnd, Subject = subject);
```

I tried to assign Timezone by converting DateTime to that Timezone and add suffix as below,

```
DateTime dt = eventStart;
String targetTZ = dt.format('Z',tzName);    // Get TZ offset for target

// Set the timezone
String dt_str = '"'+dt.year()+'-'+dt.month()+'-'+dt.day()+'T'+dt.hour()+':'+dt.minute()+':'+dt.second()+'.000'+targetTZ+'"' ;

eventStart = (Datetime)JSON.deserialize(dt_str, Datetime.class);
```

But it seems this does not setting the Timezone, when DateTime object is initialized, seems it's assigning current user's Timezone instead.

What is the correct way to set Timezone in Event?

Appreciate any help, thoughts to correct this.
Thank you!

Comment: How is eventStart being initialized?

Comment: Hi @GlenDeMarcos updated question. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the neatest thing, but you could used the `format()` method of the DateTime class to convert the DateTime to a string with an adjusted timezone, and then convert it back to DateTime. More information about the `format()` method can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_3).

```
String timeFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss';
String timeZone = 'Pacific/Auckland';

DateTime convertedStart = DateTime.valueOf(eventStart.format(timeFormat, timeZone));
DateTime convertedEnd = DateTime.valueOf(eventStart.format(timeFormat, timeZone));;

insert new Event(
    OwnerId = userIdwithDifferentTimezone, 
    StartDateTime = convertedStart, 
    EndDateTime = convertedEnd, 
    Subject = subject
);
```

Comment: Hi @Nicholas, Thanks, I tried it before. This also seems to create Event in current User's timezone. At the time when Datetime object is initialized it assigns current user's Timezone. But when you format it to a different timezone string representation seems to be in that user's timezone. and once it's back to Datetime instance using Datetime.ValueOf() or Deserialize like I did, it seems to be in current user's timezone.

Comment: Interesting. I tested it myself and found that it worked as I would have expected it to.  I set the start time to be 2019-11-12 07:00:00 in EST, but when I ran the above code it created the event with a start time of  2019-11-12 04:00:00.